# Setting up Python with WSGI on Apache for a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to setup Python with WSGI for a particular directory on Apache but I am getting the following error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3857): Target WSGI script '/var/www/test/test.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
```

My test.py contains:

```
print 'Hello, World!'
```

And my wsgi.conf contains:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/bin/python2.7

Alias /test/ /var/www/test/test.py

<Directory /var/www/test>
    SetHandler wsgi-script
    Options ExecCGI
    Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

On top of all that, interestingly enough, the web browser returns a "404 Not Found" error but thankfully the error_log is a little more enlightening.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using WSGI as though it was CGI (strangely without headers).

What you need to do, for your immediate problem is adapt the following from http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

So that you have `application` present.

And from the referenced doc.

> Note that mod_wsgi requires that the WSGI application entry point be
>   called 'application'. If you want to call it something else then you
>   would need to configure mod_wsgi explicitly to use the other name.
>   Thus, don't go arbitrarily changing the name of the function. If you
>   do, even if you set up everything else correctly the application will
>   not be found.

Comment: WSGICallableObject appfunctionname

Comment: I know this is out of date, but this returns ` TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str found` for me